# Eclipse navigator and project explorer sort the numbers in files names wrong

Tags: eclipse, interface

For instance, when I have the following files:

1. pro0.cpp
2. pro1.cpp
3. pro2.cpp
4. pro3.cpp
5. pro10.cpp
6. pro11.cpp

I expect to see them in the above-mentioned order. But Eclipse would sort them like the following:

1. pro0.cpp
2. pro1.cpp
3. pro10.cpp
4. pro11.cpp
5. pro2.cpp
6. pro3.cpp

I made a lookup but I failed to find any related information about that issue. Is not it an issue at all? Or did this problem only occurred to me?

Answer (score 0):

This is working as intended. These views just sort the file names using the result of the Java `String.compareTo` method. This just compares the strings character by character left to right. It does not try and look for numbers in the strings. This gives the result you see.

Some file viewers (macOS Finder for one) do look for numbers in the file names and sort using the whole number. This is quite a bit more complex and the Eclipse views don't try to do this.